# SSRS not showing data on report where as my sp return data

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Hello I have a ssrs report which I am showing it on report viewer on my aspx page. I have a drop down where it shows all the student information which are active. Where I need to see the report for inactive student data also when I navigate to that student. My stored procedure is returning data but where as my RDL drop down is displaying active data information I am not able to view the report. So is there a way to resolve the dependency so that I need to show the data that is returning from my SP. When  the RDL drop down show the inactive student information I am able to see the report

Comment: Please edit your question so one can understand what you want. What is an "RDL dropdown"? What does "resolve the dependency" mean?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean report parameters when you say RDL Dropdown. How are you filtering active / inactive students in your Parameter? Does your store procedure filter on active or inactive students via a parameter? Have too many questions about your questions

Comment: I have a stored procedure where it will return all active students to my RDL drop down, where as from my aspx I will pass a student which is inactive. Let's say the active ids are 1,2,3 which are binded to dropdown. I will have 4 as inactive

Answer (score 1):

can you view your rdl in bids? Make sure if you make any edits to delete .data file from bin folder on your local solution and retry. IF all behaves on SP side and rendered per your needs locally; i see no reason why it would NOT show in report server. Worse case, create a test folder on report server and deploy your report there. putting on connection settings and re-test.